# dog crates: okay to share?

Tags: dogs, crate, territory

I have 2 dogs. My wife and I recently purchased two identical crates for each of them.

Is it okay if they swap crates? We thought that they would each want to "own" one that the other one wouldn't be allowed in. I haven't been able to find any resources confirming or denying that that is something they care about.

They don't seem to mind switching back and forth, but I want to break this sooner than later if it might be problematic later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: If your dogs are properly socialized, just let them figure that out on their own. If it isn't a problem now, it shouldn't be one later on. If one prefers a specific place, it will try to get and keep it.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't really matter.  Dogs can and will argue over food, but don't seem to over sleeping spaces.

Our Labrador will sometimes go to sleep in our Schnauzer's bed (we've had the Lab for six months and the Schnauzer forever).  When the Schnauzer sees the other dog in her bed, she'll just find somewhere else to sleep.

However, if you habitually feed dogs in the crate, this could create issues.